# Cómo puedo buscar el directorio en la carpeta public desde una ruta agregada al dominio

Tags: php

```
@php
$directory = opendir('/images/events/96331140/');

    while (($img = $directory->read()) !== false) { 
        if (preg_match('/jpg/', $img)) { 
            echo "<img src='img/$img'>"; 
        } 
    }
@endphp
```

Con el código anterior recibo el error: opendir(/images/events/96331140/,/images/events/96331140/): El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada. (code: 3).

No encuentra la ruta porque tengo una ruta definida así: midominio.com/events, el código al buscar la carpeta lo hace en la siguiente rute events/images/events/96331140/

Por ello intenté con el siguiente código resolver quitando "events" de la ruta pero opendir() y dir() no la leen porque incluye el http:// en la ruta, el eeror que muestra es: opendir(http://midominio.com/images/events/96331140): failed to open dir: not implemented

```
@php
$directory = opendir(URL::to('/images/events/96331140/'));

    while (($img = $directory->read()) !== false) { 
        if (preg_match('/jpg/', $img)) { 
            echo "<img src='img/$img'>"; 
        } 
    }
@endphp
```

Cómo podría hacer para que lea la ruta de la siguiente manera: /images/events/96331140/? tomando en cuenta que el directorio está en public

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando la función `asset()` o `secure_asset()` si necesitas que sea HTTPS.

Estas funciones necesitan la url relative con respecto a public es decir, si necesitas la url hacia una imagen en `/public/img/photo.img` utiliza `asset('/public/img/photo.img')`

Para poder ser utilizado con `opendir()` utiliza `public_path() . '/ruta'` en su lugar, public_path te devolvera la ruta hacia la carpeta public.

Comment: Gracias, funciona, pero ahora tengo el error que no permite mostrar el contenido: failed to open dir: not implemented

Comment: He añadido en la respuesta como conseguir la url para open_dir

Comment: Así? $directory = open_dir(public_path('/public/images/events/96331140/'));

                            while (($img = $directory->read()) !== false) { 
                                if (preg_match('/jpg/', $img)) { 
                                    echo "<img src='img/$img'>"; 
                                } 
                            }

Comment: También intenté así, y no funciona: $directory = opendir(public_path('/public/images/events/96331140/'));

                            while (($img = $directory->read()) !== false) { 
                                if (preg_match('/jpg/', $img)) { 
                                    echo "<img src='img/$img'>"; 
                                } 
                            }

Comment: `$directory = opendir(public_path('/images/events/96331140/')`

Comment: La diferencia es opendir() y open_dir()

Comment: No, al parecer funcionó así porque no me da error, voy a cargar las imagenes en el directorio para probar: $directory = dir(public_path('/images/events/96331140/')

Comment: Aun asi, te aconsejo que le eches un vistazo al sistema storage y disks de Laravel, si necesitas leer carpetas, etc. Te simplificara mucho las cosas.

Comment: Gracias, lo revisaré